# Pandas: Get std of datetime in groupped dataframe

Tags: pandas

If I have following dataframe, how I can find the standard deviation of **day** and **Count**? I googgled and tried several options like `pd.rolling_std`, but can't figure out how to do it for days?

I also would like to have in column the `df['day'].iloc[[0, -1]`, e.g. the raw number of days of activity.

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to get the **output** like:

```
|-------|-----------|------------|-----------------|
| Slug  | std. day  | std. count | lifetime (days) |
| slug1 | 3         |  2.04      |   4             |
| slug2 | 1.6       |  1.04      |   2             |
```

Comment: Can you add desired output from your sample?

Comment: @jezrael, Hello, thanks for response, added in the end of question

Comment: Sorry, but in input are not `slug1`, `slug2`. also `lifetime (days)` is `sum`? Not first value is `6` ? Can you explain it?

Comment: I think `1+2+1+2=6`

Comment: Sorry for confusion: `lifetime (days)` is the difference in days of first and last date. The purpose is to get the insight of the slug -- on how long will the new slug be active?  Firstly, I'd like to see these stats, then I will build model (out of question's scope)

Comment: Hmmm, so first value is `2017-05-17 - 2017-04-28`? Not `4`? also `std. day` is count from `1 2 1 2`? But I get `0.547723`. Sorry, I dont understand what need.

Comment: Sorry again for confusion. The desired output is the example of random integers that I wrote from off top of dome =) I need the way (code) how I can compute std for day and for Count in case with my groupped dataframe

Comment: Ok, now understand. I want desired output from your input for verifying my solution, so with your output (random data) it is impossible. Because do you need resample data? Or only extract days like `28,2,3,17,28` as `integers` and get `std`? Similar with column `Count`? Because without your desired output for me it is hard understand what need exactly Alo becasue I am not mathematic or statistics :(